# Column not properly aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I properly align, the data of my column status? It is when I update a data to it, it will not align just like in the first picture.

[image]

[image]

```
$('#btn_edit').click(function(){
            var brand_id = $('#brand_id').val();
            var brand_name = $('#brand_name').val();
            var brand_status = $('#brand_status').val();

            $.ajax({
                url       : 'edit_brand.php',
                method    : 'POST',
                data      : {brand_name : brand_name, brand_status : brand_status, brand_id : brand_id},
                success   : function(response) {
                                $('#'+brand_id).children('td[data-target=brand_name]').text(brand_name);
                                if (brand_status == "Available") {
                                    $('#'+brand_id).children('td[data-target=brand_status]').replaceWith("<span class='label label-success'>Available</span>");
                                } else {
                                    $('#'+brand_id).children('td[data-target=brand_status]').replaceWith("<span class='label label-danger'>Not Available</span>");
                                }
                                $('#modal-edit').modal('toggle');
                            }
            });
```

Comment: It looks aligned only.
How do you want?

Comment: Yeah, but when I tried to put an alignment on my span tag. Yet, it is not working.

Comment: What does your css look like? Should both of the labels be centered vertically? The buttons in the Action column seems fine, but the labels and text in the status and brand name columns are not centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are replacing a td with a span, try replacing the td content like this:

```
$('#'+brand_id).children('td[data-target=brand_status]').html(brand_status == "Available" ? "<span class='label label-success'>Available</span>" : "<span class='label label-danger'>Not Available</span>");
```

Edit: little edit, you can now replace the entire if-else block ;)

Comment: Damn! It is now working. I didn't know using html here. I thought only replaceWith to change the data of it. But, yeah I already change it using the children. Haha. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.